# Probability in two batches

Tags: probability

I'm learning statistics and trying to solve the following problem:

> Concentration of a chemical in water is given by a continuous random
> variable with probability density:
>
> $f(x)= \left\{\begin{matrix} \frac{3}{8}x^2, & 0\leq x\leq 2 \\  0, &
>  else \end{matrix}\right.$
>
> We assume that concentrations $X$ and $Y$ of the chemical in two
> different batches are independent random variables with same same
> probability distribution.
>
> Calculate the probability, that concentration of chemical in the first batch will be higher than the concentration in the second batch.

Could you please help me on how I would solve the problem? I'm not sure how to begin.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per independence, the joint density is the following

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{3}{8}x^2\frac{3}{8}y^2$$

in the square $[0;2]\times[0;2]$

To calculate the requested probability just solve

$$\mathbb{P}[Y>X]=\int_0^2f_X(x)\Bigg[\int_{x}^2f_Y(y)dy\Bigg]dx=\dots=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: You get the same answer in the end, but, for the sake of clarity, you really should have $\int_{0}^2\int_0^xf_{XY}(x,y)dydx$

Comment: @MatthewHolder : this depends which axes you label as first or second. I labeled x-axes as second

Comment: I understand; I'm just looking out for the person who originally posted this question who's learning this stuff for the first time.

Comment: You also defined a joint density in the initial part of your solution but used marginals in your final computation, which may confuse the intended audience.

Comment: @MatthewHolder : sorry Matt....you are right, I wrongly wrote $P(X>Y)$ instead of $P(Y>X)$. Thanks, edited